# Symfony route parameter requirement restriction

Tags: symfony1

How do I enforce a requirement that a paramater in a route be a string?

Given the route

my_foobar_route:
  url: /example/routing/:s1/:id
  requirements: { id: \d+ }

Can anyone remind me of how to force param s1 to be a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to supply a suitable regular expression:

```
my_foobar_route:
  url: /example/routing/:s1/:id
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    s1: "[a-zA-Z]+"
```

**Edit**: Added quotation marks around the second regular expression; YAML interprets `[...]` as being an array of parameters. Thanks [@chiborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/130121/chiborg) :-)

Comment: Edited, thanks. Always forget about the `[]` being interpreted as a YAML array, my usual regular expressions in routing nearly always end up being `\d+` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care what the string contains or if you don't know beforehand what it will contain, try the following:

```
my_foobar_route:
  url: /example/routing/:s1/:id
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    s1: "[^/]+"
```

This will allow all characters except the '/' character which is used as a separator for the parameters. With the expression

```
my_foobar_route:
  url: /example/routing/:s1/:id
  requirements:
    id: \d+
    s1: "[^/]{3,}"
```

you could force the string to be at least three characters long.

**Don't forget to put Regexes with square brackets in quotes!** If you forget them, the YAML parser for the routes will interpret them as an array expression.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much anything that comes via the url is a string - any requirement is stronger than this, you you do not need to do anything, your parameter is already a string. Maybe you want a specially formatted string?